# Finding the Fibonacci term from the Fibonacci number

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Given that the Fibonacci number is 165580141
Is it possible to find $n$ using the closed form. I tried simplifying the closed form but I get stuck at:

$\sqrt5F_n = (\frac{(1+\sqrt5}{2})^n - (\frac{(1+\sqrt5}{2})^n$

$\sqrt5(165580141) + (\frac{(1+\sqrt5}{2})^n = (\frac{(1+\sqrt5}{2})^n$

($370248451 + (\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})^n)^{1/n} = \frac{(1+\sqrt5)}{2}$

I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: This is a very small number.  $n=41$ if you start from $F_1=F_2=1$.

Answer (score 3):

You mean
$$\sqrt5 F_n=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^n-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\right)^n.$$
The second term is very small so
$$\sqrt5 F_n\approx\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^n.$$
If you know $F_n$ and want to find $n$, why not take logarithms?

Answer (score 1):

*Just for illustration of Lord Shark the Unknown's suggestion.*

Define $k_n$ as $$k_n=\frac{\log \left(\sqrt{5} F_n\right)}{\log (\phi )}$$ and compute for a few values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & k_n \\
 3 & 3.112696029 \\
 4 & 3.955287767 \\
 5 & 5.016827815 \\
 6 & 5.993536209 \\
 7 & 7.002463652 \\
 8 & 7.999058197 \\
 9 & 9.000359624 \\
 10 & 9.999862619 \\
 11 & 11.00005247 \\
 12 & 11.99997996 \\
 13 & 13.00000766 \\
 14 & 13.99999708 \\
 15 & 15.00000112 \\
 16 & 15.99999957 \\
 17 & 17.00000016 \\
 18 & 17.99999994 \\
 19 & 19.00000002 \\
 20 & 19.99999999
\end{array}
\right)$$